# Stop Xcode from truncating NSLogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Whenever I `NSLog` multiple times in a short time, `Xcode` randomly truncates some of them like:

```
2015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-28 22:00:00 +0000, day: 29, week: 2015-53
2015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-29 22:00:00 +0002015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-30 22:00:00 +0000, day: 31, week: 2015-53
2015-11-25 15:53:47.208 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0000, day: 1, week: 2015-53
```

when it should look like this:

```
2015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-28 22:00:00 +0000, day: 29, week: 2015-53
2015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-29 22:00:00 +0000, day: 30, week: 2015-53
2015-11-25 15:53:47.207 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-30 22:00:00 +0000, day: 31, week: 2015-53
2015-11-25 15:53:47.208 AppName[97163:38002062] date: 2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0000, day: 1, week: 2015-53
```

Some other times, the logs are coming in the wrong order too.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Code snippet (requiring [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)):

```
for (NSInteger year = 2015; year <= 2016; year++) {
    for (NSInteger month = (year == 2015 ? 11 : 1); month <= (year == 2015 ? 12 : 2); month++) {
        for (NSInteger day = 1; day <= (month == 11 ? 30 : 31); day++) {
            NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithYear:year month:month day:day];

            NSLog(@"INFO: date: %@, day: %d, week: %d-%d", date, (int)day, (int)[date yearForWeekOfYearWithCalendar:calendar], (int)[date weekOfYearWithCalendar:calendar]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why is this happening but i'm assuming that console is occupied with a process and it doesn't have the time to correctly show information, but adding a "\n" in the end of each NSLog could help

Comment: Tried `\n` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code please?

Comment: @BrooksHanes, Updated my question. Though it doesn't matter too much, I get this problem whenever I log intensive working code like date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that they're in the wrong *order* sometimes is a clue--it looks like you're calling `NSLog` on a thread, and not only are the threads executing in an order that you don't expect, but clearly they can sometimes stomp on each other. You can wrap your calls to `NSLog` inside calls to `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSLog(...) })` to prevent them from stomping on each other. If you want them to execute in a specific order, though, then the *callers* have to be executed synchronously, not asynchronously.